# Stability of numerical solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

I want to solve the ODE
\begin{array}{ll}
-u''(x)=f(x) & x\in (0,1) \\
u(0)=g(0) \\
u(1)=g(1)\,  \\
\end{array}

with finite differences using $u''(x)\approx \frac{u(x-h)-2u(x)+u(x+h)}{h^2}$.
To approximate $[0,1]$ I use a grid $T=\{0=x_0<\dots , x_n=1\}$.

This leads to the equations $\frac{1}{h^2}(-u_{i-1}+2u_i-u_{i+1})=f(x_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$, $u_0=g(x_0), u_n=g(x_n)$ and the linear system
\begin{align}
 A=\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &  &\cdots & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_0\\
\vdots \\
u_n
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{g(0)}{h^2} \\
f(x_1)\\
\vdots\\
f(x_{n-1})\\
\frac{g(1)}{h^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
I already showed that $(Av)_i<0 \Rightarrow v_i<0$ for all $i=0,\dots ,n$.
How can I show that there exists $C>0$ so that $\|u\|_\infty\leq C\big (\|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty\big )$ ?($u$ is a solution of the linear system)